# Can't find installation directory of Pivotal tc server in eclipse

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

I have successfully installed spring tool suite n eclipse jee and now setting up the Pivotal tc server but I can't locate the installation directory of the Pivotal tc server in eclipse. Please help...

Comment: I installed the sts package via zip file so where does the default installation directory of Pivotal tc server as it's stated that it was bundled with it.... Why the downvote please explain...

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install tc-server-addon. Go to "Spring Dashboard" => "IDE Extensions" and install "Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition".

To find out the location of install, goto Preferences =>  Server => Runtime Environments. Here, you can notice the newly installed TC Server. Click edit and it would show the installation directory.

On Mac, it is installed under /Applications directory.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is  your directory path contains whitespace.

For eg, try to change `D:\New folder` to `D:\Newfolder`.

and change tc server properties in STS to the path without whitespace one.

Comment: Where does the default installation directory of tc server when installed via  eclipse marketplace?